# Have users confirm password changes through an email link

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to enforce regular password changes and have users confirm this password change through email? Use case would be that this would help identifying potentially compromised accounts used by crawlers.

A potential use case would be to detect compromised accounts. Someone in possession of such an account would also need access to the account owners email address to complete a mandatory password change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the question with a use case.